# expressionengine2 Wygwam editor special characters

Tags: ckeditor, editor, wysiwyg, text-editor, expressionengine

I want to have Diacritical r in my wygwam editor's special character list. I have some special characters at the moment but not Řř. Can anyone tell me how to enable/add this please?

[Current special character list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h5Z5.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a user of wygwam but is there an equivalent of CKEDITOR.config in the EE implementation?  Docs: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-specialChars